# Footer floating to the right no matter what

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float, footer

I'm trying to align a few items that are in the `section` and then in `div` horizontally but after floating them to the `left` and putting `footer` tag in the bottom of the document .The `footer` always `floats` to the `right` and to the side of the content ,and if I try to increase the `width` of the section to 40% or more it just pushes the content of the `section` to the bottom instead of the footer

HTML

```
<body>
    <section id="box">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="box">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png"
                    height="150px" alt="">
                <h3>HTML markup</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At laboriosam quod debitis quae odit
                    nesciunt alias quas facere pariatur exercitationem.</p>
            </div>


            <div class="box">
                <div class="box"></div>
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png"
                    alt="" height="150px">
                <h3>CSS3</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At laboriosam quod debitis quae odit
                    nesciunt alias quas facere pariatur exercitationem.</p>
            </div>


            <div class="box">
                <img src="https://designrfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Graphic-_Design.jpg" height="140px" alt="" w>
                <h3>Grahpic</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At laboriosam quod debitis quae odit
                    nesciunt alias quas facere pariatur exercitationem.</p>
            </div>


        </div>


    </section>
    
    <footer>Testing testing testing:: copyright 2017 &copy;</footer>

</body>
```

CSS

```
#box .box {

    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using flexbox for this kind of layout. the section can be wrapped by div and using `display: flex;` to push away the `<footer>`(check the `flex-center`class). I also suggest you to using `display: flex;`, `flex-direction: column;` and `text-align: center;` to vertically align and center every content (check the `flex-col`class). In addition, if some images may be stretched, you can use `object-fit: contain;` to fix it. Moreover, I set the footer position fixed at the bottom by `position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0;`(check the `footer` in the css ).

(((*Also, it would be nice to have more spaces between each column.*)))

```css
#box .box {
  /* float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  /* text-align: center; */
}

.flex-center {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-col img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="" id="box">
      <div class="container flex-center">
        <div class="box flex-col">
          <img
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png"
            height="150px"
            alt=""
          />
          <h3>HTML markup</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At
            laboriosam quod debitis quae odit nesciunt alias quas facere
            pariatur exercitationem.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="box flex-col">
          <!-- <div class="box"></div> -->
          <img
            src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d5/CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-CSS3_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png"
            alt=""
            height="150px"
          />
          <h3>CSS3</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At
            laboriosam quod debitis quae odit nesciunt alias quas facere
            pariatur exercitationem.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="box flex-col">
          <img
            src="https://designrfix.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Graphic-_Design.jpg"
            height="140px"
            alt=""
            w
          />
          <h3>Grahpic</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. At
            laboriosam quod debitis quae odit nesciunt alias quas facere
            pariatur exercitationem.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>Testing testing testing:: copyright 2017 &copy;</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used  `clear:both` in `footer` and it worked .